# Synonym for travel worn

Tags: synonyms

I want to describe an inanimate object as being travel worn but am unable to find a suitable replacement.

The intended meaning is to convey something which has been affected by the passage of time, is not completely destroyed but has come out weakened.

E.g. - Two *travel-worn* statues stood guard by the entrance.

Comment: ***Timeworn***: in bad condition because of age.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See **fatigue**
[ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/fatigue)

> Weakness in materials, especially metal, caused by repeated variations of stress.

Also try **dilapidated**.

[MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dilapidate)

> to bring into a condition of decay or partial ruin.

*The two statutes are dilapidated by travel, passage of time or use.*

Also see [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metal_Fatigue) on metal fatigue.

Comment: Fatigue sounds exactly like what I want... Thank you @vickyace

Comment: @user96551 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metal_Fatigue